# How do you automate period change in excel by changing number within cell?

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

I am currently working on an excel assignment for Master Planning Schedules and struggling to automate the change in period.

In order to calculate the planned receipts in cell E11 I am required to take the sum of all cells for the given period stated in the periodic time box.

To do this I originally used the SUM(E8:F8) to calculate the total but realized if I manually altered the period the formula will not account for this.

Is there any way to automate this using a formula so if the period changes from 2 to 3 it will take the cells (E8:G8) instead of (E8:F8)?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Yes that is possible. Try exploring the [OFFSET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function. Btw, what version of Excel are you using?